# Consuming Streaming API Call using HTTP Web Request

Tags: c#, live-streaming

I have a live streaming API call(Twitter Stream via Datasift) which I have to consume and show it in my application. When I tried to consume it in the browser, the call never ended. It just kept on pushing the data as it happened. And that is the point of the Live streaming actually. When I tried to consume it using HTTP Web Request Get Method, the Response Stream never ended and so I wasn't able to read the stream.  I understand this is not the way to do it. Can some one suggest me how to do it in c#.

Edited: (Extra Information)
The API returns the data continuously as and when some one has tweeted with the keyword we sent as a parameter in the API call. So the response never actually ends. When I tried doing it asynchronously, it hit the call back method only once and I wasn't able to read the stream either. Where as when I tried the same API call from a browser, it kept on giving the results as and when some one has tweeted with the keyword. SO it is just not about asynchronous consuming of web request.